# Dialogflow: Google Assistant App for Android Wear?

Tags: wear-os, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I try to build a Google Assistant app with Dialogflow.

And it works, I can test the "testversion" of my assistant app on my mobile phone too. It works as expected.

But unfortunately if I use my android wear, it tells me that this app is not supported on this device.

On Dialogflow, I couldn't find a option to enable wearables devices.

Can someone help me to enable wearable support?

Kind Regards
Stefan

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is from here [enter link description here](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/7314149?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

To use your Google Assistant on your watch, you’ll need:

A watch running Android Wear 2.0 and up

A Google Account on the watch

Phone’s language set to a language listed above

An Internet connection on your watch via a Bluetooth connection through Wi-Fi or cellular connection

Comment: yes, all these preconditions are fullfilled. My google assistent works generally on the app. standard commands like "set timer etc..." works, but if i say the trigger for my own google assistant app it says that this app is not supported on my device/wear